# Mass spring system. Find the undamped position function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

The title says it all. How do I find the undamped position function in general for 2nd order ODE with a forcing function equal to $0$? Here is an example. I am working on a problem $$\frac{1}{2}x'' + 3x'+4x=0$$
$$ \to x''+6x'+8x=0$$

the damped position function is $x(t)= 4e^{-2t}-2e^{-4t}$

I have no idea how the undamped position function becomes $2\cos(2\sqrt{2}t)$

If I got a complex root for an answer I think I get partially there. But still wont get the answer entirely. Since this problem has no complex roots I don't even know where to start to get the undamped position function. When I have a complex number for roots it looks like all I do is take what ever I have for $cos$ as the answer and subtract $\mathbb{\alpha}$ from x, ($cos(ax-\mathbb{\alpha})$ but I know that is not right. I need clarification.

Comment: There must be an error in either your equation or in the given solution. A purely oscillatory solution (like $\cos$ function) can be found only if the term corresponding to $x'$ is zero.

Comment: my answer matches the back of the book and the question matches

Comment: @DavidG.Stork can you go into detail?

Comment: Presumably your notation should be $x(t)=...$. Also, how did you pick the constants multiplying the exponentials??? Any constants will do here in absence of explicit initial conditions. If your answer matches and the question matches, what is the issue?

Comment: @copper.hat the question has two parts. The second part is find the position function. Which I cant figure out.

Comment: @copper.hat there were initial conditions given and I solved for the constants

Comment: Other than $x(t)$ I cannot even guess what the position function might be.

Comment: @copper.hat,@Andrei,@DavidG.Stork I forgot to lay out a key piece of information. It is the undamped position function

Comment: What has that got to do with the above ode? Is the $3 x'$ term removed? This would match up with the whole $\cos$ thing.

Comment: That's the answer. In your initial (damped) situation there is a coefficient of $x'$. If you are then told that the system is to be undamped, then you have $\frac 12 x''+4x=0$

Comment: @copper.hat I don't know maybe it is with the $3x'$ term removed. Its hard to get exactly what it is from the textbook. What would it look like if the $3x$ removed? could you show the steps?

Comment: Can someone show the algebra for the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks for the **undamped** position.  Thus the (undamped) equations of motion are

$$\frac{1}{2} x^{\prime \prime} (t) + 4 x(t) = 0 $$

which has the solution $x(t) = \cos{(2\sqrt{2}t)} + c$.

Comment: okay I get a characteristic polynomial of $r^2+8=0$ Then I get $r = +-\sqrt{-8}$ which comes out to be $r=-+2\sqrt{-2}$ which I am having trouble simplifying..can you show me the algebra? Where does 2 infront of cos come from?